# Updating Database with value from datepicker control ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

Apologies in advance, for what may be a newbie question.  (new to asp.net, coding in VB, zero knowledge of best controls).  Please respect that I am not interested in AJAX controls, or using MVC and trying to minimise javascript. What I need to do is very simple in terms of technology.

I am developing a form that allows users to Edit database data.  I have chosen to use FormView so that I can format it like a legacy vba app.  I am able to set the data source to my database table and the values from the database successfully show up if I allow VWD to automatically format the control.  I can edit everything in the database using this form as well.

However, the boss hates having to type dates.

I haven't been able to find a datepicker control with a datasource feature that works like the text boxes that are automatically built in formview (with a bind to a datasource feature). So, I am assuming none exist.  I need some assurances that what I *think* I need to do is the right way.

Instead of using the FormView control's datasource via the front-end automagical stuff, I should instead

- place one of these datapicker controls that simply combine calendar with a text box for all date fields in the formview (no disrespect to those who built them, just can't believe they are not more feature-rich, this seems so needed giving the number of datepickers available)
- declare my data source in Page_Load and load all the controls if they have existing data utilising FindControl
- use Data_Bound block to retrieve the selected values from each control utilising FindControl and build a dynamic SQL string for Update
- declare and update my database using one of the code behind blocks, perhaps in the DataBound

Am I on the right track?  I have no experience to be confident in my assumption.
and please, if there is an easier way, I'll take it, but I have to make it "pretty".
And suggestions for controls of any sort are welcomed.

---Further into my issue
Here is some code to prove I've actually tried to resolve this...
In my FormView code block I have:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="MASTERID_Action" 
    DataSourceID="srcAction">
<EditItemTemplate>
MASTERID_Action:
<asp:Label ID="MASTERID_ActionLabel1" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("MASTERID_Action") %>' />
<br />
Action_Description:
<asp:TextBox ID="Action_DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Action_Description") %>' />
<br />
Action_Target:
<asp:TextBox ID="Action_TargetTextBox" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Action_Target") %>' />
<br />
Action_Captured:
<asp:TextBox ID="Action_CapturedTextBox" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Action_Captured") %>' />
<br />
Action_Declined:
<asp:TextBox ID="Action_DeclinedTextBox" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Action_Declined") %>' />
<br />
Action_AgreedDate:
<ewc:CalendarPopup ID="CalendarPopup1" runat="server" Culture="en-AU" 
PostedDate="" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("Action_AgreedDate") %>' 
SelectedValue="01/14/2013 08:47:54" UpperBoundDate="12/31/9999 23:59:59" 
VisibleDate="01/14/2013 08:47:54" />
<br />
         ...
</EditItemTemplate>
```

My database holds this Action_AgreedDate as nullable.
When I view the ItemTemplate (in the browser) the date shows up as 0.000 (because its a text field and bound to Action_AgreedDate, no error occurs) and when I click Edit to go to the EditItemTemplate I get this error:
Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.

Source Error:

Line 95:             
Line 96:             Action_AgreedDate:
Line 97:             ' 
Line 99:                 SelectedValue="01/14/2013 08:47:54" UpperBoundDate="12/31/9999 23:59:59"

I can easily translate this into "the control found a null field and doesn't know what to do with it"; problem is, I don't know what to do.  I have checked the properties of the field (the CalendarPOP field to see if there is a setting for handling nulls and nothing is obvious to me.  I'm currently trying to find further documentation on the control online. (I've contacted eWorld and hope they will be able to respond.)

I should also add that if I request a record that already has an Action_AgreedDate I get no errors because there is a value present in the database for the control to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I ran across an article on 4GuysFromRolla.com about the RJS POP Calendar (http://preview.tinyurl.com/cerm9xv) and it ticked all the boxes.  Successfully implemented it and, because the calendar is separate from the specified text box, it doesn't have to be bound ! It works very nicely.  The 4GuysFromRolla save my bacon yet again...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you to do this would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), which has a [date picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), which can be attached to a regular ASP.NET TextBox in your FormView. So if you had FormView code that looks something like this for example:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            id:
            <asp:Label ID="idLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("solution_id") %>' />
            <br />
            date_modified:
            <asp:TextBox ID="date_modifiedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date_modified") %>' />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            id:
            <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("solution_id") %>' />
            <br />
            date_modified:
            <asp:Label ID="date_modifiedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date_modified") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

You could run something like this using jQuery UI to get a datepicker on the date_modified text box:

```
$('[id$=date_modifiedTextBox]').datepicker()
```

The `$('[id$=date_modifiedTextBox]')` part is necessary to select the ASP.NET control using jQuery, if it were just a normal element you could just use `$('.className')` or `$('#id')` or something like that. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this.   I actually found eWorld's Calendar PopUp control and it works unless the date field in the db is NULL.  I sent a note to the developer asking how to handle NULLs but have not yet received a response.  Do you know if the JQuery datepicker handles nulls?  What I'm doing is updating a record (so the datepicker field is indeed in my EditItemTemplate and it is bound to the date).   Like I said, I'll try this JQuery one but I have ZERO knowledge of JQuery syntax and the $.classname stuff is new to me.

Comment: Actually, now that I've gone and downloaded jQuery UI -- I have NO IDEA what to do with it?  I know nothing about json...  do these files replace .dlls?  clueless.  How do I reference it, how to I get the controls into my toolbox?